# Change colors of kernal density plots in R

Tags: r, density-plot

I am trying to overlay multiple density plots and would like them all to be different colors. When I use this command:

plot(density(Punta.Ona,na.rm=TRUE))

it works with no problem, but when I add

col="cornflowerblue"

I get this message:

Warning message:
In density.default(Punta.Ona, na.rm = TRUE, col = "cornflowerblue") :
  non-matched further arguments are disregarded

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that `plot(density(Punta.Ona,na.rm=TRUE), col="cornflowerblue")` may help. Next time however, try asking questions using a default dataset in R like `cars`, or `CO2`.

Comment: Alternatively, you might try `sm.density.compare` from the `sm` package, which is designed for overlaying densities.